# Check for string in text column A, return another string in column B - Excel

Tags: excel, lookup

I am trying to lookup one of 3 strings (Blue, Red, Green) in column A. In column A I have:

> row1: "Robert has Blue shorts"
>
> row2: "Maria has a Red dress"
>
> row3: "John has a Green car"

Whenever I find one of those 3 words in column A, I want to populate column B with the found instance (Green, Red, Blue).

There will always be one of these 3 words in column A, never more than one and the position of the words can be anywhere in the string.

I know how to put this in Python or SQL but I am struggling with Excel.

Can anyone share a solution if they used this in past?

Comment: do you to evaluate each line? Or just anywhere in the column?

Comment: there will be one string per row in column A (I apologize for not mentioning that).
I am trying to evaluate each row in column A and put the result in the corresponding row box, in column B.
In the above example, row1 in column B would contain Blue, row2 Red and row3 Green. I appreciate you taking time to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX({"Red","Blue","Green"},MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({" Red "," Blue "," Green "}," " & A1 & " ")),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

As a note:

You can also replace the `{"Red","Blue","Green"}` with a range reference.  So if the three words were in D1:D3 the formula would be:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$3,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & $D$1:$D$3 & " "," " & A1 & " ")),0))
```

Comment: very interesting. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman now it won't, I left the desire for the IFERROR to the OP.